# Suppose G is a metrisable topological group. Must it admit at least one of a right invariant or left invariant compatible metric?

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, topological-groups

I am reading a paper which says has a sentence 'If G is metrizable, with right-invariant compatible metric d_r...'

So I am trying to gauge how general the subsequent statements are, for which it would be useful to know what kinds of groups admit a right invariant compatible metric. Perhaps one can be constructed for all?

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a classic theorem (due to Birkhoff, IIRC) that a metrisable topological group $G$ (easily recognisable, because this is eqivalent to having a countable local base at $e$, plus being $T_0$ or better) has a right-invariant metric, compatible with the topology, and also a , possibly different (!), left-invariant metric. Some groups that are metrisable do not have a two-sided invariant metric IIRC. More advanced books in topological group theory will give the construction (and sometimes an example of the last as well). For non-$T_0$ we get invariant pseudometrics instead (but this isn't studied much).

Comment: Do you have a reference to Birkhoff's theorem?

Comment: @YCor: The original reference is: G. Birkhoff, [A note on topological groups](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1936__3__427_0.pdf), Compositio Mathematica, Volume 3 (1936), p. 427-430. He never states this, but his metric is right-invariant. The paper is still quite readable. It shows that a Hausdorff 1-st countable topological group is metrizable via a right-invariant metric.